# Margins predict outcome error r(198)

Tags: stata

I need to estimate output after `xtoprobit` estimation.

But I've got `r(198)` when I run,

```
margins, at(HealthStatus=(1(1)4)) predict(outcome(1))
```

after running,

```
xtoprobit Ages HealthStatus ChildSex Family1 Family2 FatherPresent MotherPresent FatherEducation MotherEducation Location Income, iterate(0)
```

Full syntax if needed:

```
set more off
local dir "/Users/user/Documents/STATISTICS/"
local datasave "Output/"
local slash "/"

********FLS1 & FLS2************

forvalues i=1/2 {
  local p = "FLS`i'"
  foreach j of local p {
    if "`j'" == "FLS1" {
      use `dir'`datasave'FLS`i'`slash'merge0, clear
    }
    else {
      merge m:m pidlink using `dir'`datasave'FLS`i'`slash'merge0
      keep if _merge==3
      drop _merge
    }
  }
}
duplicates drop pidlink, force
drop hhid*
save `dir'`datasave'respFLS12, replace

forvalues i=1/2 {
    use `dir'`datasave'respFLS12, clear
  merge m:m pidlink using `dir'`datasave'FLS`i'`slash'merge_panel
  keep if _merge==3
  drop _merge hhid*
  duplicates drop pidlink, force
  gen year = `i'
  save `dir'`datasave'FLS`i', replace
}

forvalues i=1/2 {
  local p = "FLS`i'"
  foreach j of local p {
    if "`j'" == "FLS1" {
      use `dir'`datasave'FLS`i', clear
    }
    else {
      append using `dir'`datasave'FLS`i'
    }
  }
}

save `dir'`datasave'panel1, replace

********FLS3 & FLS4************

forvalues i=3/4 {
  local p = "FLS`i'"
  foreach j of local p {
    if "`j'" == "FLS3" {
      use `dir'`datasave'FLS`i'`slash'merge0, clear
    }
    else {
      merge m:m pidlink using `dir'`datasave'FLS`i'`slash'merge0
      keep if _merge==3
      drop _merge
    }
  }
}
duplicates drop pidlink, force
drop hhid*
save `dir'`datasave'respFLS34, replace

forvalues i=3/4 {
    use `dir'`datasave'respFLS34, clear
  merge m:m pidlink using `dir'`datasave'FLS`i'`slash'merge_panel
  keep if _merge==3
  drop _merge hhid*
  duplicates drop pidlink, force
  gen year = `i'
  save `dir'`datasave'FLS`i', replace
}

forvalues i=3/4 {
  local p = "FLS`i'"
  foreach j of local p {
    if "`j'" == "FLS3" {
      use `dir'`datasave'FLS`i', clear
    }
    else {
      append using `dir'`datasave'FLS`i'
    }
  }
}

save `dir'`datasave'panel2, replace

**********************************

forvalues i=1/2 {
    use `dir'`datasave'panel`i', clear
  encode pidlink, gen(id)
  duplicates report id year
  duplicates drop id year, force
  xtset id year

  xtoprobit Ages HealthStatus ChildSex Family1 Family2 FatherPresent MotherPresent FatherEducation MotherEducation Location Income, iterate(0)
  margins, at(HealthStatus=(1(1)4)) predict(outcome(1))
  margins, at(HealthStatus=(1(1)4)) predict(outcome(2))
  margins, at(HealthStatus=(1(1)4)) predict(outcome(3))
  margins, at(HealthStatus=(1(1)4)) predict(outcome(4))

  margins, at(ChildSex =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(1))
  margins, at(ChildSex =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(2))
  margins, at(ChildSex =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(3))
  margins, at(ChildSex =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(4))

  margins, at(FatherPresent =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(1))
  margins, at(FatherPresent =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(2))
  margins, at(FatherPresent =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(3))
  margins, at(FatherPresent =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(4))

  margins, at(MotherPresent =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(1))
  margins, at(MotherPresent =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(2))
  margins, at(MotherPresent =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(3))
  margins, at(MotherPresent =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(4))

  margins, at(FatherEducation =(1(1)6)) predict(outcome(1))
  margins, at(FatherEducation =(1(1)6)) predict(outcome(2))
  margins, at(FatherEducation =(1(1)6)) predict(outcome(3))
  margins, at(FatherEducation =(1(1)6)) predict(outcome(4))

  margins, at(MotherEducation =(1(1)6)) predict(outcome(1))
  margins, at(MotherEducation =(1(1)6)) predict(outcome(2))
  margins, at(MotherEducation =(1(1)6)) predict(outcome(3))
  margins, at(MotherEducation =(1(1)6)) predict(outcome(4))

  margins, at(Location =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(1))
  margins, at(Location =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(2))
  margins, at(Location =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(3))
  margins, at(Location =(0(1)1)) predict(outcome(4))

  outreg2 using `dir'`datasave'panel`i', excel replace
  save `dir'`datasave'panel`i', replace
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please study https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on good questions here. Your example is not reproducible because your data are not accessible to us. In addition, the full code contains many details that are almost certainly irrelevant and uses an unexplained user-written program (`outreg2`).

`r(198)` means syntax error, but no such error is obvious to me. Conversely, this runs without error in Stata 14.1:

```
webuse tvsfpors, clear
xtset school
xtoprobit thk prethk 
margins, at(prethk = (0(1)6)) predict(outcome(1))
```

So, suggestions:

1. Can you run that without error in your Stata? If not, what happens? Which version of Stata are you using?
2. Check that the code is displayed is **exactly** what you typed.

Comment: 1) No. Same error. But thanks for you, after upgrading to 14.1, it works properly

Comment: Good that you fixed the problem. Thanks for report.